Theorem Clarification, Spanning Vector Set
I am studying linear algebra, and came across this theorem in the vector section, relating to spanning vector sequence

let $\mathbf{a_1,...,a_k}$ be a sequence of vectors in $F^n$. If $k<n$, then the sequence does not span $F^n$
proof:
let the sequence span $F^n$, by this assumption, any vector in $F^n$ is a linear combination of the sequences elements, by theorem (...) for any vector b of length n the matrix [A|\mathbf{] has atleast one solution. let A' be the staired canonical matrix that corresponds to A. because A' was made by A through a finite amount of operations, the matrix [A'|b] also has a solution, take $\mathbf{b=e_n}$, then since the system has a solution, the number of rows that aren't $0$ in the matrix $[A'|\mathbf{e_n}]$ is smaller or equal to the number of variables in the system, which is k. because the last row of the matrix isnt a $0$ row (the right-most element in it is 1) we get that all n rows of [A'|$\mathbf{e_n}$] arent $0$ rows, so $n\le k$, so if k<n, the sequence does not span $F^n$.

What I didn't understand about this proof is why does "the system has one solution" imply "the number of non $0$ rows in the matrix is smaller or equal to the number of the variables in the system".
also, i didn't quite understand the logic in this proof, and the structure of it.

I don't understand that part either, but is it necessary? The final argument seems to work just fine without it.

The proof seems pretty complicated for such a small statement. I've always found matrices messy, in particular something like "the staired canonical matrix", and it's certainly possible to do most of linear algebra without them. But it's a matter of taste.

Here is how I would repair this proof:

Erase that weird part "then since the system has a solution, the number of rows that aren't $0$ in the matrix $[A'|\mathbf{e_n}]$ is smaller or equal to the number of variables in the system",
Replace "the last row of the matrix isnt a $0$ row (the right-most element in it is 1)" by "since the system has a solution, the last row of $A'$ isn't a $0$ row (the last element in $e_n$ is $1$)"
Just before "so $n\le k$", insert "the number $n$ of rows that aren't $0$ in $A'$ is smaller than or equal to the number of variables in the system, which is $k$".

